# What is the quickest calculation to check if a number, a, is a primitive root modulo P, a prime?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Trying to find a quick calculation to check if my value is primitive rather than working out every a^n (modP) for n= 1 to p-1?

Comment: I think https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/how-to-test-if-a-number-is-a-primitive-root answer this question